# Serializing/deserializing python types (int, string, tuple, list, dict, pandas dataframe, pandas series) to share between java and python

Tags: java, python, serialization

I want to be able to call given python functions from java, pass it arguments and obtain return value. I want this to happen very transparently, without requiring to modify py file or java code. I considered many possible options. I asked elaborate questions on stackoverflow: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470221/calling-python-functions-from-py-files-from-java-and-passing-and-returning),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410339/different-better-approaches-for-calling-python-function-from-java).

However I dont think none of the ready made solution can handle pandas series, dataframe. So I resorted to doing serialize and deserialize the parameters.

I am able to do basic serialization. For example I can serialize standalone objects like int, string, tuple, list, dict (with `simplejson.dumps()`), pandas series, pandas dataframe (with `series.to_json` and `dataframe.to_json`). However, when pandas series, dataframes gets arbitrarily encapsulated inside any of the other data structures (say dictionary containing data frame at some depth/nested key) then it becomes tricky to serialize them with inbuilt methods (as I realized from [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768230/converting-python-tuple-lists-dictionaries-containing-pandas-objects-series-d) I asked couple of hours ago.)

Now I am wondering if there is any good/standard way out of this problem. Can serialization/deserialization be a good solution. OR should I start looking for something else? May be some in-memory cache from/to which I can share objects. Is there any such standard in-memory caching framework for both python and java which can be utilized without requiring to perform serialization/deserialization?

Comment: can I get some comment before someone asking to close this question? I dont think any exact question is there online asking "whether serialization/deserialization is correct approach?" or "how to approach it?" or "should I go for in-memory caching?"